# How do I make this to "save as HTML" instead of as it is "download as HTML"?

Tags: javascript, html, file, download, save

I am making an online web editor and I need this.
How do I make this into a "save as" function instead of what it is a "download function"? The difference is that in "download as" you can not decide what name it should be, but in "save as" you can decide the save file name before it saves.

**So how do I make this to "save as", instead of "download as"?**

**PS: if you could help me add a "load file" button too that works, that would be great.**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">...</style>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    window.onload = function() {
      var txt = document.getElementById('html');
      txt.value = window.onload + '';
      document.getElementById('link').onclick = function(code) {
        this.href = 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,'
          + encodeURIComponent(html.value);
      };
    };

    main();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="txtWrap">
      <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
    </div>
    <a href="" id="link" download="code.html">Download Above Code</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the HTML5 download & file APIs.

Comment: Your `main()` function doesn't exist, your `.onclick` function doesn't take a parameter, and `html` is undefined.

Comment: https://github.com/rndme/download/ lets you provide a filename and mime (like text/html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below script makes use of some HTML5 features

```js
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;
 
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
 
    downloadLink.click();
}
 
function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
 
function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
 
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
    <tr><td>Text to Save:</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <textarea id="inputTextToSave" cols="30" rows="7"  class="form-control" placeholder="enter your text here!"></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs" placeholder="example.txt" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select a File to Load:</td>
        <td><input  class="form-control" type="file" id="fileToLoad"></td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="loadFileAsText()">Load Selected File</button><td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be useful to add that this doesn't work in IE at all, and Edge wont "honour" the supplied filename

Comment: There is one tiny problem with that code of yours. And that it is, that it saves as TXT file and I want it to save as HTML file. How do I make it to save as HTML file?

Comment: With pure JS it's not possible to write files, but you can do with HTML5 W3C API ... 1. https://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/  2. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side 3. https://eligrey.com/demos/FileSaver.js/

Comment: As you see in the example above I did make it to save as a HTML file. The only problem was that it is fixed named as "code.html" unless i change the source values, but I want it to be changeble in the page but with that code I can not give it what name I want as for example MyName.html
So what I needed was a way to save the file as HTML instead of downloading it because when downloading you can not add freely your own name as in saving as.

Comment: I was thinking more like what if the button was calling to a box before for name and after that it would be saved with the function I made. There for one could save it as HTML with no problem. But how to do that code?

Answer (score 0):

**FINAL UPDATE and finished**

This I made myself. No need for query and it is the most simple and clean way of having it saved in HTML or TXT from a button and with the file name of your choice. Now I only have to make the load function another day.

**BEST solution I made if you ask me is this.**

**Example:**

Now I made an even better solution who adds .html automatically using Query to the name so it is fixed to html files.

```
<html>
<head>

<script language="Javascript" >
function download(filename, text) {
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

  pom.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(pom);

  pom.click();

  document.body.removeChild(pom);
}
</script>

    </head>
<body>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">

<textarea rows="10" cols="70" name="text" placeholder="Type your text here:"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="text" name="name" id="txt" value="" placeholder="File Name">
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="Save As">
</form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery("#btn").on('click', function() {
        var $txt = jQuery("#txt");
        var caretPos = $txt[0].selectionStart;
        var textAreaTxt = $txt.val();
        var txtToAdd = ".html";
        $txt.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```